# Create django filter choices based on current queryset

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a table with a number of category columns and I want to provide a choice filter for each category column based on the current set of values, not based on all possible values.

| year | category_a | category_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | x | a |
| 2021 | y | b |
| 2022 | z | b |

Given the above the initial `choices` for `category_a` would be `x,y,z` and `category_b` would be `a,b`. This I can achieve by using something like `self.parent.queryset.distinct('category_a')`.

However once the user applies a filter like `category_b=b`, the `choices` should only be `y,z`, i.e. something like `self.parent.qs.distinct('category_a')`. This however runs into recursion.

I'm looking through the execution path of `FilterSet`s, since it seems to me that they must be used twice in a request, once to apply the current filter data and a second time to render the filter widgets for the response, but `choices` is evaluated as part of the initial set validation, hence the recursion. Is there a way to defer the computation of `choices` until the widget is rendered?